# Plot dataframe using markers based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to plot `df2` as a regular continuous plot but using the values from `df1` to select markers.

```
DATAdict = {
    'A': [ "foo",         "miau",  "ciao" ],
    'B': [ "miau",         "haha",  "ciao"],
    }

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(DATAdict, orient='columns')

DATAdict = {
    'A': [ 0.79, 0.86, 0.88, ],
    'B': [ 0.89, 0.89, 0.90, ],
    }

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(DATAdict, orient='columns')

unique = pd.unique(df1.values.ravel('K'))

markers = {}
marker_list = ["s", "o", "+", "x", "P"]
for label, i in zip(unique, range(0, len(unique))):
    markers[label] = marker_list[i]
```

The idea is to  plot A column using `range(0,3)` for the x axis and 0.79, 0.86, etc for the y axis and then select the markers based on foo, miau and ciao.

Comment: I see, where are the markers defined? Or just any random markers? Are the markers supposed to be defined in `Dist_name`? (`Dist_name` is currently undefined in your example)

Comment: I have edited the code now. There is probably a better way to select the markers, but I think it suffices for this. Note that markers is a dict containing the unique values from df1 as keys and the items are the markers to be used when plotting df2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [`sns.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) with the `style` param:

> `style` : vector or key in data
>
> Grouping variable that will produce points with different markers. Can have a numeric dtype but will always be treated as categorical.

To connect the lines, I don't know of a way to do that with [`sns.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html), but we can overlay the line using the Axes handle:

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df2.reset_index(), x='index', y='A', style=df1['A'], s=100)
ax.plot(df2.index, df2['A'])
```

[image]

Note that seaborn chooses the `style` markers automatically. You can use the `markers` param to set them manually, **but** the markers cannot mix [filled and unfilled markers](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html):

```
marker_list = ['s', 'o', 'P', 'X'] # all "filled" type
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df2.reset_index(), x='index', y='A', style=df1['A'], markers=marker_list, s=100)
```

Comment: Almost what I am looking for. Now it is missing connecting the dots with a line.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with seaborn, but we can overlay a line plot to connect the dots

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way in matplotlib not to plot the scatter markers separately:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


DATAdict = {
    'A': [ "foo",         "miau",  "ciao" ],
    'B': [ "miau",         "haha",  "ciao"],
    }

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(DATAdict, orient='columns')

DATAdict = {
    'A': [ 0.79, 0.86, 0.88, ],
    'B': [ 0.89, 0.89, 0.90, ],
    }

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(DATAdict, orient='columns')


marker_list = ["s", "o", "+", "x", "P"]
marker_dict = dict(zip(pd.unique(df1.values.flat), marker_list))

ax = df2.plot()
row, col = df1.shape
for x, y, m, c in zip(np.repeat(np.arange(row), col), df2.values.flat, df1.values.flat, np.tile(np.arange(col), row)):
    if not c:
        ax.set_prop_cycle(None)
    ax.scatter(x, y, marker=marker_dict[m])
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]